# Setting text input field with string using Ruby Page Object

Tags: ruby, selenium, page-object-gem

Using the [Ruby Page Object Gem](https://github.com/cheezy/page-object/), I am trying to send a string to a text input field with the following html:

```
<input id="marketerAssignmentForm:marketerName" name="marketerAssignmentForm:marketerName" type="text" value="" maxlength="65" tabindex="3">
```

I set the element like so:

```
text_field(:name_form, :xpath => "//*[@id='marketerAssignmentForm:marketerName']")
```

and then call this method in my code, trying to send in the text to the input field:

```
name_form= 'my string'
```

This page object code does not fill in the input field, am i using the wrong syntax or is this field not actually a text_field?

The following basic selenium code works as I would expect the page object method to work:

```
$driver.find_element(:xpath, "//*[@id='marketerAssignmentForm:marketerName']").send_keys('my string')
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `name_form= 'my string'` just sets a local variable. You need a receiver - either `self` if calling from within a method of the page object or the page object instance.

Comment: self.name_form= 'my string' in my case works as expected. Thank you @Justin Ko